# PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF nuget package

Tags: nuget, pdfsharp, migradoc, nugetgallery

I am looking for the [PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF Nuget package](http://www.pdfsharp.net//NuGetPackage_PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF.ashx). The pdfsharp site indicates that the package exists, but it is not present in the Nuget Gallery: only a [GDI package](https://nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI/) is there. An attempt to `Install-Package` by name failed.

```
PM> Install-Package PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Is there a configuration change that I need to make (e.g. pointing to another nuget server from the company that publishes PDFsharp-MigraDoc-WPF) in order to get the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDFsharp site indicates that the NuGet package with the WPF version was not published yet.

For the WPF version you can use the source code package (reference the projects in VS) or get the DLL package.